# How to find how many pixels down a div is relative to a parent div (jquery)

Tags: jquery

To give an example, how would I find how many pixels down from the parent is child3?

```
<div class="parent" id="unique"> 
<div class="child1"></div>
<div class="child2"></div>
<div class="child3"></div>
<div class="child4"></div>
</div>
```

Assume the classes define the width, heights, padding, margins etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var child=$('.child3');
var parent=$('.parent');

return child.offset().top-parent.offset().top;
```

[`Offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) defines the element position relative to the document.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.offset()`:

```
var $child = $('.child3');
var offset = $child.parent().offset().top - $child.offset().top;
```

I'm not too sure if it accounts for borders and margins, but those shouldn't be hard to account for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the `position()` function. It returns an object containing the `top` and `left` values.

> **Description**: Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.

[Documentation for `position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

Comment: `.parent` may not be the offset parent.

Comment: @jan, I'm not 100% sure what you mean by that. The function finds the elements offset from its parent. The description says relative to the parents offset. We don't care what the parents offset actually is, only the child's offset from the parent.

Comment: No. The parent is not the same as the offset parent. The offset parent is the closest element _that is positioned relative or floats_ (approximately)